# Template class - unresolved external symbol(s)

Tags: c++, class, templates

I get this error a LOT, and i never know why. Can someone help me find the cause of it?

Edit:Removed code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the implementation (your method definitions) into the header along with the class declaration (see [this in the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html)).  Some compilers have supported an "export" keyword for doing it the way that you did, but that has been nixed in the C++0x.

Answer (score 5):

Templates must be defined in header files. See these FAQs for more info:

- [Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl)
- [How can I avoid linker errors with my template functions?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl)

Answer (score 2):

This errors are happening because, your `template` definitions are not visible to the user code. Template definition should be declared in,

1. Header file, along with the template
   declarations
2. In the .cpp file, where the user
   code uses it. However in this
   approach the definition will be
   visible only to the .cpp which uses
   it. See below example

### test.h

```
template<typename T>
void foo (T*);
```

### test.cpp

```
int main ()
{
  foo(1);
}

template<typename T>
void foo (T *p)
{
 ...
}
```

### test2.cpp

```
// This file can not see the definition of foo
```